# Performance: Vector2 vs. x/y

Tags: c#, performance, xna

I have some amount of older game code that I am porting over to XNA.  All of my objects use x/y (float) vs. Vector2 to describe various positions, etc.

Syntax, etc. aside,  is there a good performance based reason to convert my old x/y type units to Vector2, or can I just do a straight port and not have to worry about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say the main reason for using `Vector2` is that it allows you to use overloaded operators, which makes code easier to read and understand.

In terms of performance, there would be so little in it, considering almost any game would be doing much more. If anything 2 floats might be faster, as accessing a variable might be faster than accessing a struct's field (although as Merlyn has said will probably end up the same anyway).

Comment: I would expect the the access time to be the same between a float and a field in a struct.  There might be a tiny (and probably unimportant) change in JIT time, but it will probably compile down to the same or similar assembly at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Using `Vector2` is slower in two important ways:

Creating one can cause the constructor to be called (although in some typical cases it will be optimised out). This is an extra method call. (Note that it doesn't allocate memory.)

Calling methods - and that includes operators like `+` and `*` - involves a method call, which takes time. Doing maths operations directly on `float`s (and that *includes* operating directly on the `X` and `Y` members of `Vector2` - that is to say inlining the operators) doesn't involve a method call and is therefore faster.

To put an actual number on it - inlining simple operators (`+` and `*`) on `Vector3` gives a 380% speed improvement (source: "*Understanding XNA Framework Performance*" by Shawn Hargreaves).

**However** it is a lot more convenient to use the vector classes as-is. So **unless you are optimising maths-heavy code** like a particle system or physics engine, **don't worry about it!**

(Also do note that the operators on the vector types, method calls included, are already insanely fast! Making an already-fast thing faster is not nearly as useful as making a slow thing faster! There are usually better performance improvements to persue.)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a performance based answer, the best we can do is speculate.

Any time you want a performance-based answer, you have to make it perform. So I would do a port that encourages maintainability, which IMO means converting to Vector2. Then, in the course of profiling the system, you will take out whatever performance bottlenecks arise, which includes using floats vs Vector2.